# How can I change this?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

We want to make the API Code.
This is my code:

This is the display using the code below. web: https://goldmasterid.000webhostapp.com/G2G/index1.php

```
 <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://www.g2g.com/wow-us/gold-2299-19249?&server=30805&faction=543&sorting=price@asc';
//masuk ke web html
$html = file_get_html($url);
//cari rate harga

foreach($html->find('a[class^="seller__name"]') as $a) {
    echo $a->innertext.'<br />';
}

foreach($html->find('span[data-ppu]') as $span) {
    echo $span->innertext.'<br />';
}
?>
```

The results for the above code like this:

[image]

This is the example that I want:

[image]

For example like `ss` above
How can we write the code?
Please help.

Comment: I don't see you calling any API, you are scraping the website

Comment: yes sir, I scraping the website

Answer (score 0):

Add the value to an array first and loop through it at the end.

```
 <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://www.g2g.com/wow-us/gold-2299-19249?&server=30805&faction=543&sorting=price@asc';
//masuk ke web html
$html = file_get_html($url);
//cari rate harga

$atags = [];
$spanTags = [];

foreach($html->find('a[class^="seller__name"]') as $a) {
    $atags[] = $a->innertext;
}

foreach($html->find('span[data-ppu]') as $span) {
    $spanTags[] = $span->innertext;
}

for ($i = 0, $lenght = count($atags); $i < $lenght; $i++) {
  echo $atags[$i] . '<br>';
  echo $spanTags[$i] . '<br><br>';
}
?>
```

Or check if the value are in a parent div or element, grap the parent element with simple html dom and then get the 2 values.

Comment: how? I dont know how to change, pls help

Comment: The example I wrote will give you the result you mentioned in your question. Compare my code against yours and try it, If you don't understand my changes please tell me wich part you don't understand

Comment: it should like this https://i.ibb.co/XSsJWjp/image.png I don't know how to edit that code, pls help